# how can i create a table and alter right after in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, create-table, alter

My problem is that when I create the table within the stored procedure and I'm trying to alter a column, it says Invalid column name 'column_name'. As I know it happens, because the executions are parallel so the table does not exist when it tries to add the column. So is there any way that I could create the table and alter columns in a stored procedure at the same time? I've tried to do embedd stored procedures to create the table first, then alter column with another procedure within the first procedure, but I guess it still runs paralell and doesnt work. Thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: Why create then edit a column why not create it with whatever you want with it initially?

Comment: The above comment is valid but if you must do it that way i would use T-SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(v=sql.90).aspx...if you post your stored proc and what you want to achieve then people will be able to help you further

Comment: as @Dev N00B said post your procedure code

Comment: Ye,  I've changed it to create with it, but can I update and create in the same stored procedure?

Comment: again....please post the stored proc you have